# Do we have to set index to unusable state while using APPEND PARALLEL in the insert query oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, parallel-processing, insert

Do we have to set index to unusable state while using APPEND PARALLEL in the insert query oracle?

Here I'm not using SQLLDR, its a normal insert query with PARALLEL. I understood that the indexes will go to unusable state after execution but I'm not sure about setting the index to UNUSABLE before firing the insert query.
While using SQLLDR for direct-path load, we use SKIP INDEX MAINTENANCE flag to false and rebuild the index after loading the BCP.
Do we have to do something similar for normal insert query with APPEND PARALLEL?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why should a simple insert make index unusable?

Answer (score 1):

No. Index maintenance will be performed as part of the insert.

Comment: So do I have to set the index to unusable state before performing insert with APPEND PARALLEL?

Comment: @ShashankVC Nope. Just run the insert. Also, if you want the insert phase to run parallel, you will need to do;  alter session enable parallel dml